# Transforming Table Values to Column Names | Values

Tags: sql, database, select, vertica

I've got a table with two columns, Name & Value:

```
Name    Value   

col1    value1  
col2    value2  
col3    value3
```

Now, I want to SELECT from the table in such a way that 
the Name becomes Column Name and the Value becomes the value for each Column

```
col1    col2    col3    

value1  value2  value3
```

I'm writing the query in Vertica, but any sort of logical help would do.

Comment: still in doubt ?

Comment: Thanks @Up_One Really helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **DECODE** for this.

**See example :**

```
    create table bla  (
name varchar(10),
value varchar(10)
);


insert into bla values ('col1','value1');
insert into bla values ('col2','value2');
insert into bla values ('col3','value3');

SELECT 
MAX( DECODE( name , 'col1' , value ) ) AS col1 ,
MAX( DECODE( name , 'col2' , value ) ) AS col2 ,
MAX( DECODE( name , 'col3' , value ) ) AS col3 
FROM bla
```

--output

```
col1    col2    col3
value1  value2  value3
```